# Scrollable List/Table with closeable groups

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I want to create a single select scroll-able table/list which has groups that can be closed/reopened with the help of JavaScript/HTML/AngularJS like so:

[image: example]

Bonus: Make the items drag and drop compatible into another table/list.

Answer (score 0):

You can dynamically add and remove the collapsible rows to the model. If you keep track of how each row is nested, you can write a custom comparator that allows you to keep your sorting intact. It's not elegant but it should work.